# Display if picture was uploaded or not for a particular id using group by

Tags: sql-server

Schema:

```
tablename : Picture_profile
personID, pictureNumber(count which increase upon adding a picture for an id there can be many pictures),pictureName, datePictureAdded

tablename : person
personID, phone, address, zip, city, email,country and many other columns
```

Query:

```
select personID, email,country
case when count(pictureNumber)>=1 then 'yes' else 'no' PictureIsUploaded
from person_profile
left join Picture_profile on Picture_profile.personID = person_profile.personID
group by personID, email,country
```

above query works fine and displays what ever I want but the question is

If I need to display all the columns. Am I supposed to do "group by" 
for all the columns in select.

Is there a way where I can eliminate this group by?

Answer (score 0):

This only works on fairly recent versions of Sql Server, but I'd use the [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175156(v=SQL.105).aspx) operator:

```
SELECT p.*,
    COALESCE(a.HasPicture, 'N') PictureIsUploaded
FROM person_profile p
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 'Y' HasPicture 
    FROM Picture_profile pic
    WHERE pic.personID = p.personID
) a
```

You could also do this as a correlated derived table (sub query):

```
SELECT p.*,
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT TOP 1 'Y' 
         FROM Picture_profile pic
         WHERE pic.personID = p.personID)
    , 'N') PictureIsUploaded
FROM person_profile p
```

The advantage of the APPLY operator over the correlated subquery is when you want more than one value from the chosen `Picture_Profile` record. This would allow you to include, for example, both the `picturename` and `picturenumber` fields in the results, but only incur the subquery cost once.